# How to compare only date in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am new to moment.js. I have a date object and it has some time associated with it. I just want to check if that date is greater than or equal to today's date, ***excluding the time when comparing.***

```
 var dateToCompare = 2015-04-06T18:30:00.000Z
```

I just want to check if dateToCompare is equal or greater than today's date.
I have checked isSame of moment.js, but it seems to take string and only the date part. But I do not want to convert my date to string or manipulate it further. Because I am worried that javascript may do something unexpected when converting that date to string(like adding the offset or dst,etc), or may be I am wrong.

Sample isSame() from docs

```
moment('2010-10-20').isSame('2010-10-20');
```

Also I am looking for something like isSame() and isAfter() combined as one statement.

I need to compare using moment.js only.Please do not suggest plain javascript date comparison.

Answer (score 256, accepted):

[The docs are pretty clear](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/) that you pass in a second parameter to specify granularity.

> If you want to limit the granularity to a unit other than milliseconds, pass the units as the second parameter.
>
> ```
> moment('2010-10-20').isAfter('2010-01-01', 'year'); // false
> moment('2010-10-20').isAfter('2009-12-31', 'year'); // true
> ```
>
> As the second parameter determines the precision, and not just a single value to check, using day will check for year, month and day.

For your case you would pass `'day'` as the second parameter.

Comment: Thanks! seems like i don't have to convert to string. But do we have any common method for isSame() and isAfter()

Comment: I have already used that. Thanks! just wanted to see if there is a common function, not that it is difficult to use both.

Comment: @kabirbaidhya, before making sizable unsolicited edits, it is considered polite to post a comment on questions and answers noting issues. I don't feel that the edits you made were necessary, so I rolled them back. If you feel that the information was important, please consider posting your own answer.

Comment: Just to complement: 
"As the second parameter determines the precision, and not just a single value to check, using day will check for year, month and day."

Comment: This won't work on firefox if you change the format from `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: @NoobGeek There is now isSameOrBefore() and isSameOrAfter() from version 2.10.7 onwards.

Answer (score 60):

Meanwhile you can use the `isSameOrAfter` method:

```
moment('2010-10-20').isSameOrAfter('2010-10-20', 'day');
```

Docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-after/

Answer (score 15):

In my case i did following code for compare 2 dates may it will help you ...

```js
var date1 = "2010-10-20";
var date2 = "2010-10-20";
var time1 = moment(date1).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var time2 = moment(date2).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
if(time2 > time1){
    console.log('date2 is Greater than date1');
} else if(time2 < time1) {
    console.log('date2 is Less than date1');
} else {
    console.log('Both date are same');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 14):

You could use `startOf('day')` method to compare just the date

Example :

```
var dateToCompare = moment("06/04/2015 18:30:00");
var today = moment(new Date());

dateToCompare.startOf('day').isSame(today.startOf('day'));
```

Comment: Be careful while using startOf because it will update your actual date object.

Answer (score 5):

```
moment('2022-01-07').isAfter(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'), 'day');
```

checking
2022-01-07 this with current date

if current date is beyond 6th Jan 2022, it returns false!

Answer (score 4):

For checking one date is after another by using `isAfter()` method.

```
moment('2020-01-20').isAfter('2020-01-21'); // false
moment('2020-01-20').isAfter('2020-01-19'); // true
```

For checking one date is before another by using `isBefore()` method.

```
moment('2020-01-20').isBefore('2020-01-21'); // true
moment('2020-01-20').isBefore('2020-01-19'); // false
```

For checking one date is same as another by using `isSame()` method.

```
moment('2020-01-20').isSame('2020-01-21'); // false
moment('2020-01-20').isSame('2020-01-20'); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

moment('date').toDate().getTime() > moment()