# Moment.js compare two date thrown a warning

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have created a simple app, which need a date comparison. I used Moment.js, and I have tried on answer on this question:

[Compare two dates in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988525/compare-two-dates-in-js)

[Moment js date time comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600856/moment-js-date-time-comparison)

[How to compare only date in moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29494528/how-to-compare-only-date-in-moment-js)

But all of them not working for me.

**and now I use this code:**

```
if(moment('09/12/2016').isAfter('09/11/2016')){
    console.log("True")  
} else {
    console.log("False")
}
```

But in the console it's thrown a warning:

> **Deprecation warning**: moment construction falls back to js Date. This
>   is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please
>   refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

Everybody please help me. here's my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gq6ykw8L/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your date string is ambiguous between `DD/MM/YYYY` and `MM/DD/YYYY`. If you refer to the link given in the warning (http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/), it says:

> This deprecation warning is thrown when no known format is found for a
>   date passed into the string constructor. **To work around this issue,
>   specify a format for the string being passed to moment().**

You need to use [`moment(String, Format)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) to specify the format of your date string.

```
moment('09/12/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
moment('09/12/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Comment: @EngkusKusnadi, The date string inside isAfter is throwing the warning in the fiddle. Declare the second date as moment using moment(String, Format) too. See https://jsfiddle.net/ozzan/gq6ykw8L/4/

Comment: They could have added the examples that you included in your answer. But they chose not to. 
Thanks for this answer.